# CombineReducers in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

```
export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    login: loginReducer,
});
```

This works fine but as soon as I try to combine another reducer,

```
export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    login: loginReducer,
    logout: logoutReducer
});
```

I start getting an error on rootReducer that

```
'rootReducer' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.
```

How could I modify this?

This is how my logoutReducer looks like:

```
import {store} from '../index'

export const logoutReducer = (state = store.getState(), { type, payload } :any) => {
  switch (type) {
    case "logout":
      return {...state, token: payload};
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Not really, the problem is that I'm trying to use ```store.getState()```. If I replace that with let's say ```initialState```, it doesn't give an error. But I'm unable to use the getState. @keikai

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this with assigning type to your underlying reducers?

For example:

```
import {Action, Reducer} from 'redux';
interface LoginState {
   isLoggedIn: boolean;
   token: string;
}

interface LogoutState { 
   token:string;
}

export const logOutReducer: Reducer<LogoutState> = (state: LogoutState | undefined, incomingAction: Action): LogoutState=> {
switch (incomingAction.type) {
    case "logout":
      return {...state, token: payload};
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
//... export const logInReducer: Reducer<LoginState>...
```

Comment: I'm mostly taking this from the React-with-Redux project template with ASP.NET Core from VisualStudio.